# Building C++ code with ocamlbuild

Tags: c++, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have found many guides on how to build `.o` files from C sources using `ocamlbuild`.  These do not apply to C++ files, however, which `ocamlbuild` cannot build out of the box.

I have tried writing a `myocamlbuild.ml` file (shown below after request) providing a rule from `.cpp` to `.o` and that fails with `ocamlc` complaining that it does not know what to do with a `.cpp` file (even when the compiler is set to `g++` via command line flags).

```ocaml
open Ocamlbuild_plugin ;;

let ext_obj = !Options.ext_obj;;
let x_o = "%"-.-ext_obj;;

rule "ocaml C++ stubs: cpp -> o"
  ~prod:x_o
  ~dep:"%.cpp"
  begin fun env _build ->
    let c = env "%.cpp" in
    let o = env x_o in
    let comp = 
      if Tags.mem "native" (tags_of_pathname c) then !Options.ocamlopt else !Options.ocamlc in
    let cc = 
      Cmd(S[comp; T(tags_of_pathname c++"c"++"compile"); A"-custom"; A"-cc"; A"g++"; A"-c"; Px c]) in
    if Pathname.dirname o = Pathname.current_dir_name then cc
    else Seq[cc; mv (Pathname.basename o) o]
  end;;
```

The file `libsoundness.clib` consists of a bunch of `.o` files.

When I do `ocamlbuild libsoundness.a` I get the following output:

```
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ /usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -custom -cc g++ -c src/soundness/proof_aut.cpp
/usr/bin/ocamlc.opt: don't know what to do with src/soundness/proof_aut.cpp.
Usage: ocamlc <options> <files>
<snipped long list of ocamlc options>
```

The only other solution for C++ seems to be `ocamlbuild-ctools` whose website is defunct (I could not download any sources).

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you set the compiler to g++ instead of gcc ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: Could you add the contents of your myocamlbuild.ml file, as well as the command line you use to compile?

Comment: You can call the C compiler directly from `ocamlbuild` instead of `ocamlc`. I don't know if that's the proper solution though.

Comment: https://github.com/JoeDralliam/OcamlbuildCpp perhaps this is helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cf. [my answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660452/118799).

I recommend the following approach :

1. name c++ files with `.c` extension so that `ocamlc` picks them up
2. tell `gcc` that those are actually c++ files with `-x c++`
3. tell `ocamlbuild` that the build actually depends on `.h` files (e.g. list `.h` files together with `.c` in the `CSources` field in `_oasis`)
4. do not forget to link `-lstdc++` explicitely cause `gcc` will not do that being a C compiler it is
5. use [cxx_wrapped.h](https://github.com/ygrek/scraps/blob/master/cxx_wrapped.h) to get that real C++ feel
6. PROFIT!!

See [hypertable bindings](https://github.com/ygrek/ocaml-hypertable) as an example of this approach.

Comment: Thanks, I got there in the end with your suggestion. I also had to manually make compilation depend on a fixed list of header files, as none of the tools involved is clever enough to figure out C/C++ dependencies, it seems.

Comment: Indeed, added that point. I presume it would be not overly difficult to make ocamlbuild plugin to extract header deps, but for me a fixed list is good enough (I am specifying the list of `.c` files in `CSources` anyway).